# Virtual mouse is ignored by xorg when loaded

Tags: xorg, udev, input

I'm trying to run virtual mouse driver from book "Essential Linux Device Drivers"
but when I'm load this module into kernel using insmod in /var/log/Xorg.0.log I see:

```
[   757.212] (II) config/udev: Adding input device  (/dev/input/event10)
[   757.212] (II) No identifier specified, ignoring this device.
```

How can I force Xorg to don't ignoring this device? or what I must add to kernel module code?

Comment: Sounds like your learning how to write device drivers. In that case you should ask on Stackoverflow, not here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885792/virtual-mouse-linux-module-and-xorg-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: The book is 5 years old, a lot of different things have changed. Just a suggestion from a tactic I used many years ago when the kernel was more in flux and how-to were out-of-date more often than not: setup the environment the authors use in a VM and make sure everything works there. Then upgrade (one at a time) kernel, X and gcc to until things break. At least that way you know where the culprit may be and search (e.g. in ChangeLogs). It takes time compiling and installing stuff, but that needs little attendance once started.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the below lines of code in the input device driver

```
set_bit(EV_REL, vms_input_dev->evbit);
set_bit(REL_X, vms_input_dev->relbit);
set_bit(REL_Y, vms_input_dev->relbit);
```

with

```
vms_input_dev->name = "Virtual Mouse";
vms_input_dev->phys = "vmd/input0"; // "vmd" is the driver's name
vms_input_dev->id.bustype = BUS_VIRTUAL;
vms_input_dev->id.vendor  = 0x0000;
vms_input_dev->id.product = 0x0000;
vms_input_dev->id.version = 0x0000;

vms_input_dev->evbit[0] = BIT_MASK(EV_KEY) | BIT_MASK(EV_REL);
vms_input_dev->keybit[BIT_WORD(BTN_MOUSE)] = BIT_MASK(BTN_LEFT) | BIT_MASK(BTN_RIGHT) | BIT_MASK(BTN_MIDDLE);
vms_input_dev->relbit[0] = BIT_MASK(REL_X) | BIT_MASK(REL_Y);
vms_input_dev->keybit[BIT_WORD(BTN_MOUSE)] |= BIT_MASK(BTN_SIDE) | BIT_MASK(BTN_EXTRA);
vms_input_dev->relbit[0] |= BIT_MASK(REL_WHEEL);
```

It worked for me on ubuntu 12.04